# How do you CSS target li items by group/order

Tags: css

I want the first 3 items to be in red, the next 2 with green and the rest with yellow.

How to do this with CSS?

```
<ul>
    <li>1 (red)</li>
    <li>2 (red)</li>
    <li>3 (red)</li>
    <li>4 (green)</li>
    <li>5 (green)</li>
    <li>6 (yellow)</li>
    <li>7 (yellow)</li>
    <li>8 (yellow)</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you could make the red <li class="red> and so on for the different colors and then with css target it as .red{
//whatever you want}

Comment: what are you basing the colour on, the position in the list or the text of the list item? Because the position in the list is not consistent.

Comment: you can use `:nth-child()` & `~`  selector to filter and overwrite colors : `li {color:red}
li:nth-child(3)~li {color:green}
li:nth-child(5)~li {color:yellow}` and so on. demo https://jsfiddle.net/hg0sxrup/

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Thank you, that was what I want!